# Istapage wordpress plugin, how to map landing pages to categories

Tags: wordpress

I am using istapage wordpress plugin to get generate landing pages.
I want to assign them categories, is it doable?

I have urls of landing pages I want to add say 5 landing pages to first category and another 5 landing pages to an another category.

If I have links in hand can I assign them to categories?

Help me brah..